# Mysql sum child without recursive

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I have table

| AccID | AccName | Parent | Balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | B | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | A-1 | 1 | 0 |
| 4 | B-1 | 2 | 0 |
| 5 | A-1-1 | 3 | 100 |
| 6 | A-1-2 | 3 | 100 |
| 7 | B-1-1 | 4 | 0 |
| 8 | B-1-2 | 7 | 300 |
| 9 | B-1-3 | 7 | 100 |

i need help to produce :

| AccID | AccName | Parent | SumBalance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 0 | 200 |
| 2 | B | 0 | 400 |
| 3 | A-1 | 1 | 200 |
| 4 | B-1 | 2 | 400 |
| 5 | A-1-1 | 3 | 100 |
| 6 | A-1-2 | 3 | 100 |
| 7 | B-1-1 | 4 | 400 |
| 8 | B-1-2 | 7 | 300 |
| 9 | B-1-3 | 7 | 100 |

using mysql without using With CTE ie i need normal sql that sum the balance

Comment: Provided the number of hierarchy levels is limited, say never more then 5 levels, you can use 5 left joins.

Comment: If the relation is set via `Parent` then either recurse or (if max. nesting level is limited) joining multiple table copies. If `AccName` can be used (in shown data - no, AccID 8 and 9 does not match) then single query with 2 table copies is possible.

Comment: the relation is on parent
How i can perform this